# Excel.Office.Interop is returning double even when it is an integer

Tags: c#, excel

The following gets objects from an Excel spreadsheet that are castable to `string` or castable to `double`.  The trouble is that even if I know the object is visibly an integer, formatted as "General" inside the spreadsheet, Excel.Office.Interop always returns a `double`.  While it would be easy to convert the double to the nearest `int`, is there a way to get an object castable to an `int`?

```
    // returns null if the cell is empty
    // returns an object castable to a string if it is a string
    // returns an object castable to a double if it is a floating point or integer number

    internal object GetCell(int row, int column)
    {
        if ((row != 0) && (column != 0) && (worksheet != null))
        {
            string cellName = ExcelCellReference(row, column);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oneCellRange;
            oneCellRange = worksheet.get_Range(cellName, cellName);
            object oneObject;

            // contrary to MSDN, the value Empty, checkable with method IsEmpty() 
            // does not work if the cell was empty.
            // instead, what happens is that null is returned.
            oneObject = 
               (object)
oneCellRange.get_Value(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);

            return oneObject;
        }
        else
        {
            if (worksheet == null)
                throw new Exception("null worksheet reference");
            else
                throw new Exception("invalid argument");
        }
    }
```

Edit: If every number in Excel is represented as a floating point number, even if visibly an integer, then that would explain this behavior, in which case there is no solution other than conversion.

Edit: People keep posting conversion answers.  This is question is meant to solicit idiomatic `Interop` answers, not conversion answers.

Edit: Chris's answer in a comment `int i = (int)(double)GetCell(r, c)` is arguably correct but not what I had in mind because the conversion is happening outside of `Interop`.

Comment: I suspect your edit sums it up and that it stores everything as floating point. However if you know something is an int surely a `GetInt(...)` method that just says `(int)(double)myObject` isn't too problematic is it?

Comment: Your guess is correct. There is no such thing as an integer in excel cells. The only types available are `Number`, `Text`, `Logical` and `Error`. `Number` is mapped to Double in the interop

Comment: @adrianm, excellent, the mystery is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `adrianm`,

> There is no such thing as an integer in excel cells. The only types
>   available are Number, Text, Logical and Error. Number is mapped to
>   Double in the interop.

So the answer is to just cast the double to an int, which as`Chris` points out actually works. Note that if the double is not equal to an integer to begin with, you might want to do a more suitable conversion according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `ToString()` your object, then parse using `int.Parse(...)` or `int.TryParse(...)` ?

Comment: because you could more easily just cast to double and then to integer? Going via a string seems unnecessary...

Comment: @Chris, I don't think doubles can cast to int.  `kjhf`, the answer is because it's better to have Microsoft.Office.Interop return an int if it can.

Comment: @broiyan: have you tried? Because I did... `object foo = 2.0;int bar = (int)(double)foo;`.

Comment: This cast is surprising.  I just did `int i = (int)9.9d;` and it becomes 9.  I wonder if this is new-ish or if it was also in C or C++.

Comment: When you cast a double to an int it truncates the decimal portion.  If you want to round then use `int rounded = (int)(Math.Round(dbl))`

Comment: @DStanley, since a double equal to an integer will always cast to that integer this is a good conversion.  There is a 52 bit mantissa in the double and the int has fewer bits, so there is no problem.  In general `integerType i = (integerType)(myFloat + 0.5f)` might be less risky.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `object` into `double` and then into `int`, but you should take care as `double` value is much bigger than `int`. so better convert your `double` into `long`.

Try This:

```
object val = /*your value*/;
double db = Convert.ToDouble(val);
long x = Convert.ToInt64(db);
```

Comment: Why not just long x = Convert.ToInt64(val); ?

Comment: Sudhakar, because it's better to have `Interop` return an int, if possible.

Comment: @broiyan so you want to get `int` from this statement -> `oneCellRange.get_Value(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
` ?